How to recover a tokens in base network that was sent to a non listed exchange in base network
Can anyone help? I transferred some tokens from the Metamask base network wallet to the Binance base network but later, I found that the token was not listed on Binance, and Binance customer care said they couldn't do anything, so is there any way to recover those tokens back to my Metamask wallet?

Unfortunately there's nothing you could do. Only Binance has the private key of the wallet. Centralized exchanges have policies defined for cases like this, from they won't do anything to charge a large fee to solve the problem.
